# Happstack - hello world server

Tags: haskell, happstack

```
main = simpleHTTP nullConf $ ok "Hello, World!"
```

i am a newbie trying out haskell with `happstack-server`. In this hello world program, i got these doubts:

1) Server's default configuration, `nullConf`, where is it defined? at least it is not there in `$HOME/.cabal/Happstack/Server.hs`

2) What does `$` symbol in the middle of function arguments mean?

3) Is there any way, i can force cabal to download source libraries instead of compiled haskell binaries? That will help me a lot in source code debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Both `simpleHTTP` and `nullConf` will be defined in whatever library you're importing.

2) The `$` symbol is mentioned in a dozen Haskell tutorials and Stack Overflow questions; basically it allows you to avoid putting stuff in brackets.

3) Cabal *already* downloads everything as source code. But it immediately compiles it into binaries and then deletes the sources. However, if you read the package documentation on Hackage, every page has a "Source Code" link that will show you syntax-highlighted code, right in your browser. (Just make sure you're reading the same package version as the one you have installed!)

Comment: about `$` symbol, not putting function arguments in brackets is the convention in haskell right...

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It's for if you have something like `f1 (f2 (f3 (f4 x)))`, you can instead write `f1 $ f2 $ f3 $ f4 x`. A bit like a shell pipeline.